# How to autocomplete text in a textview with firebase database in an android app

Tags: android, search, firebase, autocomplete, firebase-realtime-database

I want something like below image. [Image is of autocomplete search from firebase website itself.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v684r.jpg)

I've seen many post about this, but those posts does not seem to work with firebase above 3.0.

I want to search in an autcomplete textview either with entering name or number. [Here's an entry from my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZYQ3.jpg)

In short, it should suggest entries from my firebase database as I start typing.

Answer (score 0):

One solution for achieving this would be loading your data from the realtime database into an ArrayList before you start searching.

1. So to do this first you'll need to check when the Firebase Listener
   is done retrieving your data from the database.
    Firebase Listeners are not executed in sequence and the ValueListener is always executed last. So you can do something like retrieve your data through a ChildListener and then execute to ValueListener to make sure the data is completely retrieved `rootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent()`
2. Later when your data is retrieved and stored in a arraylist you can follow [this](http://codetheory.in/adding-search-to-android/) to add the search functionality

   Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

First of all add the required dependencies of firebase and glide or other dependency for image view in build.gradle .
Create a reference for the tree as follows

```
mUserDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("YourTreeRootNameHere");
```

Pass the string in the text field with a onTextChanged method to the following function firebaseUserSearch. Make necessary changes in the following function according to your code.

```
  private void firebaseUserSearch(String searchText) {

    Query firebaseSearchQuery = mUserDatabase.orderByChild("sName").startAt(searchText).endAt(searchText + "\uf8ff");

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users, SearchActivity.UsersViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users, SearchActivity.UsersViewHolder>(

            Users.class,
            R.layout.list_layout,
            SearchActivity.UsersViewHolder.class,
            firebaseSearchQuery

    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(SearchActivity.UsersViewHolder viewHolder, final Users model, final int position) {


            viewHolder.setDetails(getApplicationContext(), model.getName(), model.getPlace(), model.getImage());



        }
    };

    mResultList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

}


// View Holder Class

public static class UsersViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    View mView;

    public UsersViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mView = itemView;

    }

    public void setDetails(Context ctx, String userName, String userStatus, String userImage){

        TextView user_name = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.name_text);
        TextView user_status = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.status_text);
        ImageView user_image = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);


        user_name.setText(userName);
        user_status.setText(userStatus);

        Glide.with(ctx).load(userImage).into(user_image);


    }




}
```

Create your layout for recyclerView and define the data model class. For example this function uses a Users.class that is shown below.

```
public class Users {

public String name, image, place;

public Users(){

}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public String getPlace() {
    return place;
}

public void setPlace(String status) {
    this.place = status;
}

public Users(String name, String image, String place) {
    this.name = name;
    this.image = image;
    this.place = place;
}
}
```